# How to set visibility scales for ArcGIS for Server image service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, mosaic

I have created a mosaic dataset in ArcGIS 10.3.1 and from it I created an image service which works okay. However, how would I set the visibility scale range on this service so that, for example, the service only displays between 1:10,000 and 1:50,000? I could of course load the layer into an mxd and set the visibility scale here and then publish as a map service, but then that wouldn´t be an image service any more.

Comment: I don't think it is possible - you'll probably have to set the visibility scales in the layer settings in Desktop or in your Web app configuration.  There is however some options for visibility scales when creating a Referenced Mosaic Dataset from a Raster Catalog or a Mosaic dataset e.g. Maximum Visible Cell Size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could of course load the layer into an mxd and set the visibility
>   scale here and then publish as a map service, but then that wouldn´t
>   be an image service any more.

what do you mean by that wouldn't be an image service.
if you will define the cache of the service upon publishing (create only the extents you need).

[image]
the map server will act as a proper image service\raster
this is how it looks in the REST:
[image]